# Base R reshape() versus tidyverse

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, tidyverse

Recently I was looking around to find a quick way to create a long data frame out of a wide data frame containing patient data with multiple measurements per patient (let's say a heart rate, blood pressure, and saturation score for up to five days). While googling around I had expected to find numerous solutions from the tidyverse and/or the reshape2 package. However, I actual found [this gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9684963/503175) from base-R.

Now I cannot let go of trying to find an equally nice "one-liner" using one or more of the packages in the tidyverse and/or reshape2. So far, nothing as nice comes up and I'd appreciate a hint. Note that this question is explicitly about a pretty/neat, clever solution rather than finding the actual solution.

Data from linked post:

```
id <- paste('x', "1.", 1:10, sep="")
set.seed(10)
DF <- data.frame(id, trt=sample(c('cnt', 'tr'), 10, T), work.T1=runif(10),
    play.T1=runif(10), talk.T1=runif(10), total.T1=runif(10),
    work.T2=runif(10), play.T2=runif(10), talk.T2=runif(10), 
    total.T2=runif(10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a tidyverse solution with a single function call, but a good solution is not that complicated either. We need to gather first, then separate the time and keys, and then spread it back again.

```
DF %>% 
    gather(key, val, -id, -trt) %>% 
    separate(key, c('key', 'time')) %>% 
    spread(key, val)
```

> ```
>       id trt time       play       talk      total       work
> 1   x1.1  tr   T1 0.86472123 0.53559704 0.27548386 0.65165567
> 2   x1.1  tr   T2 0.03188816 0.07557029 0.86138244 0.35432806
> 3  x1.10 cnt   T1 0.35589774 0.50050323 0.80154700 0.83613414
> 4  x1.10 cnt   T2 0.21913855 0.20795168 0.17015172 0.50528560
> 5   x1.2 cnt   T1 0.61535242 0.09308813 0.22890394 0.56773775
> 6   x1.2 cnt   T2 0.11446759 0.53442678 0.46439198 0.93643254
> 7   x1.3 cnt   T1 0.77510990 0.16980304 0.01443391 0.11350898
> 8   x1.3 cnt   T2 0.46893548 0.64135658 0.22286743 0.24586639
> 9   x1.4  tr   T1 0.35556869 0.89983245 0.72896456 0.59592531
> 10  x1.4  tr   T2 0.39698674 0.52573932 0.62354960 0.47314146
> 11  x1.5 cnt   T1 0.40584997 0.42263761 0.24988047 0.35804998
> 12  x1.5 cnt   T2 0.83361919 0.03928139 0.20364770 0.19156087
> 13  x1.6 cnt   T1 0.70664691 0.74774647 0.16118328 0.42880942
> 14  x1.6 cnt   T2 0.76112174 0.54585984 0.01967341 0.58322197
> 15  x1.7 cnt   T1 0.83828767 0.82265258 0.01704265 0.05190332
> 16  x1.7 cnt   T2 0.57335645 0.37276310 0.79799301 0.45947319
> 17  x1.8 cnt   T1 0.23958913 0.95465365 0.48610035 0.26417767
> 18  x1.8 cnt   T2 0.44750805 0.96130241 0.27431890 0.46743405
> 19  x1.9  tr   T1 0.77077153 0.68544451 0.10290017 0.39879073
> 20  x1.9  tr   T2 0.08380201 0.25734157 0.16660910 0.39983256
> ```

Comment: Ah, that's it, now I realize that by removing the vars that are ID "cruft", gather actually gathers the whole remaining lot under one heading. That can then be separated out. I was looking too much for a solution that already specified what columns would go under which new column.