# Reshaping a dataframe with a single |Date|Temperature_1|Temperature_2|Temperature_3|etc ..... into |Date |Temperature| form

Tags: r, dplyr

I have temperature dataframe from 37 stations. First column is date and from second to last column are temperature from 1-37 stations. I need to arrange the data in such a way that, the result contains Date column and temperature column from station 1 - 37. Such that the date column is repeated after every station.

I tried

```r
library(dplyr)
tmax_1 %>% select('Date', 'V1')
tmax_2 %>% select('Date', 'V2')
tmax_3 %>% select('Date', V3)
tmax_4 %>% select('Date', V4)
tmax_5 %>% select('Date', V5)
tmax_6 %>% select('Date', V6)
```

But this takes lot of typing. Can anyone suggest better solution in case i need to do it for more than 1000 stations!!![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to make "long" data from "wide" data. `tidyr` has `gather()` which does that.

As you have given the header format in your question *which you could've done in a better way* you can try:

`tidyr::gather(df, key = "Station", value = "Temperature", -Date)`

In this you'll create a column called `Station` that will contain the names or the id's of the station acording to the old column names, and the `Temperature` column that will contain the temperature values acording to the cels. The last argument `-Date` is to exclude the Date column from undergoing the same transformation. You can learn more about `gather()` and `spread()` on the [Rstudio blog](https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/), and other questions on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684671/wide-to-long-multiple-measures-each-time).

And next time it could be helpful if you gave some visualisation of your data or a reproducible example and the expected result.